# Reading a csv persisted list of floats back into a list of floats

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I have persisted a list of floats in a csv file and it appears thus (a single row).

```
"[6.61501123e-04 1.23390303e-04 1.59454121e-03 2.17852772e-02
  :
 3.02987776e-04 3.83064064e-03 6.90607396e-04 3.30468375e-03
 2.78064613e-02]"
```

Now when converting reading back to a list, I am using the `ast` literal_eval approach:
`probs = [float(p) for p in ast.literal_eval(row['prob_array'])]`

And I get this error:

```
    probs = [float(p) for p in ast.literal_eval(row['prob_array'])]
  File "/Users/santino/anaconda/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 49, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
  File "/Users/santino/anaconda/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 37, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    [6.61501123e-04 1.23390303e-04 1.59454121e-03 2.17852772e-02
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Not sure how I can instruct ast to read the exponent syntax, or am I wrong in assuming it's the exponent syntax that is causing the exception.

Edit: I used csv.DictWriter to persist into the csv file. Is there a different way I should be persisting?

Edit2:

```
with open("./input_file.csv","w") as r:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(r,fieldnames=["item_id","item_name","prob_array"])
    writer.writeheader()
        res_list = ...
        for i,res in enumerate(res_list):
            row_dict = {}
            row_dict['item_id'] = id_list[i]
            row_dict['prob_array'] = res
            row_dict['item_name'] = item_list[i]
            writer.writerow(row_dict)
```

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` wont complete because your list is not in proper list format (elements separated by a comma surrounded by outer brackets).

Comment: I used csv.Dictwriter to write to the csv, how else can I persist?

Comment: That doesn't look like a `csv` - no commas. Can you show your `csv` writing code?

Comment: Usually, the answer is that you shouldn't be storing a list of floats as a single column in a CSV file, but instead storing each float as its own column. But if you really do need to store a list of floats, don't store the repr of the list, use a nested CSV, or JSON, or some other format designed for persistence and therefore trivial to parse.

Comment: A `DictWriter` will write values to a single column header (fieldname). As it looks, that "list" is really just a string with brackets on the end and space separation. Does it represent a whole row in the CSV file? Or just one column?

Comment: added the csv writer code, is pretty straightforward. will likely takeup @abarnert idea of saving in json.

Comment: @abarnert can you post your response as answer? so I can accept it

Comment: @Santino OK, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV only stores string columns. Using it to store strings, ints, floats, and a few other basic types is fine, as long as you manually convert the objects: whenever you do `str(i)` to an int, you can get the int back with `int(s)`.

But that isn't true for a list of floats. There's no function you can use to get back the result of `str(lst)` on an arbitrary list.<sup>1</sup> And it isn't true for… whatever you have, which seems to be most likely a numpy array or Pandas Series… either.<sup>2</sup>

If you can store each float as a separate column, instead of storing a list of them in a single column, that's the easiest answer. But it may not be appropriate.<sup>3</sup>

So, you just need to pick some other function to use in place of the implicit `str`, which *can* be reversed with a simple function call. There are formats designed for persisting data to strings—JSON, XML, even a nested CSV—so that's the first place to look.

---

Usually JSON should be the first one you look at. As long as it can handle all of your data (and it definitely can here), it's dead simple to use, someone's already thought throw all the annoying edge cases, and there's code to parse it for every platform in the universe.

So, you write the value like this:

```
row_dict['prob_array'] = json.dumps(res)
```

And then you can read it back like this:

```
prob_array = json.loads(row['prob_array'])
```

If `prob_array` is actually a numpy arrays or Pandas series or something rather than a list, you'll want to either convert through `list`, or use numpy or Pandas JSON methods instead of the stdlib module.

The only real problem here is that if you want the CSV to be human-readable/editable, the escaped commas and quotes could be pretty ugly.

---

In this case, you can define a simpler format that's still easy to write and parse for your specific data, and also more human-readable, like just space-separated floats:

```
row_dict['prob_array'] = ' '.join(map(str, res))

prob_array = [float(val) for val in row['prob_array'].split()]
```

---

<sub>1. Sometimes you can use `ast.literal_eval`, but relying on that is never a good idea, and it isn't working here.</sub>

<sub>2. The human-readable format used by numpy and Pandas is even less parser-friendly than the one used by Python lists. You *could* switch to their `repr` instead of their `str`, but it still isn't going to `ast.literal_eval`.</sub>

<sub>3. For an obvious example, imagine a table with two different arbitrary-length lists…</sub>